# How do I upload an .mdf file to Azure Data Studio for Mac?

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, mac-os-x

How could I access multiple databases at once using Azure Data Studio and import an existing .mdf file as one of those database, with tables and data that had been stored in that .mdf file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure Data Studio is like SQL Server Management Studio: these are client programs that access SQL Server, but ADS and SSMS don't touch the MDF files directly.

What you need is SQL Server to open the MDF. Try [downloading SQL Server Developer Edition](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads) - it's free. Once it's installed, follow the [instructions on how to attach a database.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/attach-a-database?view=sql-server-2017) Attaching a database is kinda like opening a .doc file in Word - you need Word installed first.

Comment: Is SQL Server Developer Edition available for Mac?

Comment: Sure, on the Mac, you can use a Docker container.

Comment: I uploaded Microsoft Access files into Azure Data Studio, and it worked great. Thanks!